All gamma control software fails silently
Related but non-functional: Is there a software utility to adjust screen gamma/brightness/contrast?
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS"

$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*XWAYLAND0 1920/340x1080/190+0+0  XWAYLAND0

$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --gamma 10:10:10
# does nothing

$ xgamma -gamma 10
-> Red  1.000, Green  1.000, Blue  1.000
<- Red  1.000, Green  1.000, Blue  1.000
# does nothing

$ redshift -ov -g 0.1.:0.1:0.1 -m randr
Temperatures: 6500K at day, 4500K at night
Brightness: 1.00:1.00
Gamma (Daytime): 0.100, 0.100, 0.100
Gamma (Night): 0.100, 0.100, 0.100
Period: Daytime
Color temperature: 6500K
Brightness: 1.00
# does nothing

$ redshift -ov -g 10.:10:10 -m wayland
Temperatures: 6500K at day, 4500K at night
Brightness: 1.00:1.00
Gamma (Daytime): 10.000, 10.000, 10.000
Gamma (Night): 10.000, 10.000, 10.000
Failed to start adjustment method wayland.

May or may not be causative:
$ dmesg
[87497.277737] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1
[87511.857920] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 0
[87512.550997] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1
[88099.324821] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 0
[88101.309864] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1
[88568.169127] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 0
[88632.570716] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1
[88706.039734] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 0
[88708.855773] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1
[88709.966779] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 0
[88737.919422] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1
[88738.219316] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 0

